# Is there a way to convert morris.js charts to image?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, morris.js

I have used morris.js charts. Now I want to be able to export all of my page HTML to PDF, which includes these morris.js charts. I am using iTextSharp for PDF export, but it does not recognize SVG elements.

Answer (score 0):

SVG is not supported by iText 5.
SVG support is under development for iText 7. It will not be backported to iText 5.

Meanwhile you can use Batik to convert SVG to PNG, and then put the PNG image in your PDF. Awkward, I know, but it's your best option for now.